# Reading multiple files in Fortran 95

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am writing codes in Fortran 95, to read a number of files looking like 1.dat, 2.dat, ......, 9999.dat. I have a code that reads 0001.dat, 0002.dat, .......... 9999.dat. It looks like

```
character*12, fn
..
DO i=1,n
    write(fn,*)i
    open(1,file=fn)
    do j=1,5
       read(1,*)x(i,j),y(i,j),z(i,j)
        end do
 10  format(i4.4,'.dat')
```

May you suggest me how can I make it possible to read the files that I have please? Thanks.u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change your format to

```
10    format (i4,'.dat')
```

I tried this for instance

```
      character *8 filename

      do i=1,9999
        write (filename, 10) i  
        write (*,*) filename
      end do

10    format (i4,'.dat')

      end
```

And I had no leading zeros in my file names.

Is this hat you were looking for ?

**Update**
I see...

Then the format should be

```
10    format (i0,'.dat')
```

the '0' means left justified.

I tested it with the following pgm

```
    character*12, fn

    integer x(11,5)
    integer y(11,5)
    integer z(11,5)

    do i=1,11
        write(fn,10)i
        open(1,file=fn)
        do j=1,5
            read(1,*)x(i,j),y(i,j),z(i,j)
        end do
        close(1)
    end do

10  format(i0,'.dat')

    end
```

And that worked for me.

**Update 2**

```
    implicit none

    integer n,ns,i,j

    real x(9999,400),y(9999,400),z(9999,400),a(9999,400),aa(400)

    character*12, fn

        n =  14
    ns = 2  

    do i = 0,n
        do j = 1, 5
                a(i,j) = 0.0
            end do
    end do

    do i=1,n               
        write(fn,10)i
        open(1,file=fn)

        do j=1,5
                read(1,*)x(i,j),y(i,j),z(i,j)
                if(i.le.ns) then
                     a(i,j) = x(i,j)
            else
                 a(i,j) = x(i,j) + a(i-ns,j)
                end if
            aa(j) = a(i,j)
            write(*,*) j,x(i,j),y(i,j),z(i,j),a(i,j)
        end do
        close(1)

        do j = 1, 5
            write(*,*) aa(j)
        end do
    end do

10  format(i0,'.dat')       

    end
```

Worked for me.

Output (on Ubuntu 10.10).

```
./a.out
           1   1.0000000       3.0000000       5.0000000       1.0000000    
           2   2.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       2.0000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       3.0000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       8.0000000       1.0000000    
           5   1.0000000       4.0000000       8.0000000       1.0000000    
   1.0000000    
   2.0000000    
   3.0000000    
   1.0000000    
   1.0000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       3.0000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       7.0000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       3.0000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       1.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       3.0000000    
   3.0000000    
   7.0000000    
   3.0000000    
   1.0000000    
   3.0000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       4.0000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       9.0000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       6.0000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       2.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       4.0000000    
   4.0000000    
   9.0000000    
   6.0000000    
   2.0000000    
   4.0000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       6.0000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       14.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       6.0000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       2.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       6.0000000    
   6.0000000    
   14.000000    
   6.0000000    
   2.0000000    
   6.0000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       16.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       3.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       7.0000000    
   7.0000000    
   16.000000    
   9.0000000    
   3.0000000    
   7.0000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       9.0000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       21.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       9.0000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       3.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       9.0000000    
   9.0000000    
   21.000000    
   9.0000000    
   3.0000000    
   9.0000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       10.000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       23.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       12.000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       4.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       10.000000    
   10.000000    
   23.000000    
   12.000000    
   4.0000000    
   10.000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       12.000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       28.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       12.000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       4.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       12.000000    
   12.000000    
   28.000000    
   12.000000    
   4.0000000    
   12.000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       13.000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       30.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       15.000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       5.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       13.000000    
   13.000000    
   30.000000    
   15.000000    
   5.0000000    
   13.000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       15.000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       35.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       15.000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       5.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       15.000000    
   15.000000    
   35.000000    
   15.000000    
   5.0000000    
   15.000000    
           1   3.0000000       8.0000000       5.0000000       16.000000    
           2   7.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       37.000000    
           3   3.0000000       7.0000000       8.0000000       18.000000    
           4   1.0000000       4.0000000       10.000000       6.0000000    
           5   3.0000000       5.0000000       7.0000000       16.000000    
   16.000000    
   37.000000    
   18.000000    
   6.0000000    
   16.000000    
At line 23 of file c.for (unit = 1, file = '12.dat')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Comment: Thanks Alain. However I got the same error like: list in: end of file apparent state: unit 1 named 1.dat last format: list io lately reading sequential formatted external IO Aborted How do you think of this please?

Comment: Could you update the question with a sampling of these files so that we can provide you with a simple reading program ?

Comment: Sure. Actually I work in Linux [Ubuntu] and I wrote data file myself. I am not sure how I can provide you my data file to you.But it includes 3 columns and 9 rows. Nothing more. The program can read if I renamed the files like 0001.dat, 0002.dat instead 1.dat, 2.dat.

Comment: Weird. You did not forget to close the files right ?  I can't see close(1) in your loop.

Comment: No no I have that I just forgot to select and copy. I have that one just after end do.I am sure.

Comment: It works if I do this :    10  format(i1,'.dat')      until 1.dat, 2.dat .......7.dat files.

Comment: Dear skaffman MAy you suggest me how I can sove my problem please?

Comment: I think I understood.  You need to left justify the file index when generating the file name.  See the update.

Comment: Thanks Alain. The files that I am to take care of are generated from C++ and they look like exactly the artificial files 1.dat, 2.dat, ...... ,9999.dat. I could not get the files from C++ in the format of 0001.dat, 0002.dat, ......, 9999.dat. So I had to think of the program in Fortran to read and process the files. Anyway I will see your updates. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Is there any way to change the name of files from 1.dat, 2.dat, ...., 9999.dat to 0001.dat, 0002.dat, ......, 9999.dat ?

Comment: Do you mean in c++ ? When you create them ? yes: use "%04d.dat" format instead of "%d.dat". Should do it.  But did you try my test.  I'm pretty sure that works too...

Comment: I tried but it gives the same error. May you check my update for that please?  Yes exactly I am thinking in other way so that I could get my data files in the format that I need that is 0001.dat .....9999.dat. But I do not use any format scheme while writing the data in C++. So, I could not follow you please.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see any update.  Can you post your entire code + one file.  To do that, just click "edit" in your original post and paste the text. I'll take care of the rest...  Don't give up ;-)

Comment: I did that twice but I do not know I was said that I am not allowed to edit the text. Is there any way to do that please?

Comment: I did paste it can you see now?

Comment: Did you not take the link ?  I need some link or some way to retrieve it.  Tens of people use pastebin every minute ou know.

Comment: Sorry but everything works OK here.  The file 1.dat had only 4 lines. I added one to maje it run. But for sure the pgm runs well from 1.dat to 11.dat (I copied 2.dat several times till 11.dat).  Update 2 lists the pgm and the output.